# how to build libuv for android platform

Tags: c++, libuv, readme

In `libuv` readme part about building for android, doing the instructions results in a toolchain. How does that relate to the library? Should I build `libuv` with the resulted toolchain?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can build the toolchain and do make as suggested in the readme. 
Then add the resultant toolchain to the path and use it to compile any program /files.

you can try

```
aarch64-linux-android-gcc yourfile.c -L/~/libuv/out/Debug  -luv
```